# How to create a certain number of regions with a given patch-size in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I need to create a number of regions which have a given patch-size. The total number of regions is 100.

I start with these data:

A list whose components are the number of regions with the same size (the sum of the components must be 100) and another list whose components are the patch-size of these regions. Therefore, if L1 = (n1, n2, n3) and L2 = (s1, s2, s3), it means that n1 regions have a patch-size of s1, and so on.

So I start creating a list with 100 components, where the first n3 components have a value equal to s3, the following n2 components have a value of s2, and the following n1 components have a value of s1.

```
to setup-world

    let plot-distribution (list 9 20 25 15 11 5 5 5 4) ;sum = 100
    let plot-patches (list 1 3 7 15 29 49 77 141 392)

    let plot-list (list)

    (foreach plot-distribution plot-patches [
          let aux ?2
          repeat ?1 [set plot-list (fput aux plot-list)]
    ]) 

...
end
```

Then I start a foreach loop, to create each region I need. I start asking one random patch to be (let's say) green. Then, I define its "neighborhood" as the patch-set of neighbor patches with color black. If the number of patches in neighborhood is greater than the patches I need to color, then I color all the neighborhood; if not, I just net to color a smaller number of patches. Afterwards I redefine the new "neighborhood" as black patches of the old "neighborhood", to keep processing the loop.

```
to setup-world
...

foreach plot-list
  [
    let counter 1 ;;;;number of patches colored
    let max_counter ? ;;;;number of patches of the region
    let colorete one-of base-colors ;color
    let neighborhood 0 ;;;;start a variable for the patch-set

    ;;;; Set one random patch with a random color and set a region of
    ;;;; its neighbours which have black color
    ask one-of patches with [pcolor = black]
    [
      set pcolor colorete
      set neighborhood (patch-set neighbors with [pcolor = black])
    ]

    ;;;; Start the loop to complete the region

    while [counter < max_counter ] ;;;;while the amount of colored patches is smaller than the total size of the region
      [
        let patch-number (count neighborhood)

      ;;;; If the number of patches I have to color is greater than the number of patches of "neighbourhood", then color all the patches. Otherwise, ask a smaller group of patches in neighborhood, since it has more patches than those I need to color.

        ifelse ( (max_counter - counter) > patch-number ) 

        [ask neighborhood [
            set pcolor colorete
            set counter (counter + patch-number)
            set neighborhood (patch-set (neighbors with [pcolor = black]))
          ]
        ][ 
          ask n-of (max_counter - counter) neighborhood [set pcolor colorete]
          set counter (max_counter)
          ]
      ]
  ]

...
end
```

However, it cannot complete the loop; it gets stuck, and I don't know why. I have tried creating instructions more simpler (and somehow, repetitive), just to be more "clear", but it's useless.

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Try adding `print` statements to print diagnostic output as the while loop runs, so you can see what it's doing as it goes along. This should help you determining what is actually happening when it "gets stuck".

Comment: Agree with Seth, printing key variables (counters etc, but also what patch you're on) is the best debugging option here. At the very least, however, you have a logic problem if it happens to choose a black patch surrounded by patches that are already allocated - though I think that would get an error when you `ask neighborhood` rather than an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good idea. I solved the problem. It was an infinite loop because I forgotten to update the neighborhood as `set neighborhood (patch-set **neighborhood** neighbors with [pcolor = black])`